# Queue Linked List based implementation in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

I wrote my implementation to Queue Linked List based. And I need a review for it to improve it and improve my coding skill. I also will put this implementation on my GitHub account.

```
//======================================================
// Author      : Omar_Hafez
// Created     : 30 July 2022 (Saturday)  8:02:31 AM
//======================================================

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
class Queue {
    
    private:
        struct Node {
            T value;
            std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
            Node (T data, std::shared_ptr<Node> ptr) : value(data), next(ptr) {}
        };
        
        int size_value = 0;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> back;
        std::shared_ptr<Node> front;

    public:
        enum QueueOpStatus { FailedQueueEmpty = -1, FailedQueueFull = -2, OK = 1 };

        //  this constructor is to keep the consistency with the array based implementation
        Queue(int MAX_SIZE = 1000000) {}

        QueueOpStatus push(T const& t) {
            if(full()) return FailedQueueFull;
            if(front) {
                back->next = std::make_shared<Node>(t, nullptr);
                back = back->next;
            } else {
                front = std::make_shared<Node>(t, nullptr);
                back = front;
            }
            size_value++;
            return OK;
        }

        QueueOpStatus pop() {
            if (empty()) return FailedQueueEmpty;
            front = front->next;
            size_value--;
            return OK;
        }

        bool empty() const { return size_value == 0; }

        bool full() const { return 0; }

        int size() const { return size_value; }

        T top() const { 
            if(empty()) {
                throw "Queue is empty";
            }
            return front->value; 
        }

        void clear() {
            while(!empty()) {
                pop();
            }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `push` could be streamlined: `back` will always point to the new node no matter what:

  ```
    auto new_node = make_shared<Node>(t, nullptr);
    if (front) {
        back->next = new_node;
    } else {
        front = new_node;
    }
    back = new_node;
  ```
- The emptiness of the queue is tested differently in `push` (which tests `if (front)`) versus `pop`/`top` (which tests `empty()` aka `size_value == 0`). Technically nothing is wrong, but it gives an uneasy feeling. Better use an uniform test.
- `top` throwing an exception *could be* an overkill. Consider returning a `std::pair<bool, T>`, or `std::optional<T>`.
- `size_value` shall be `size_t`.
- To repeat another review, `enqueue/dequeue` are far better than `push/pop`.